# How to increase default Drupal minimum cache lifetime options to a custom value?

Tags: caching, 7

Currently the max page cache age is 1 day. I would like to icnrease to 1 year. How can I do that?

These settings are located at
/admin/config/development/performance

- "Minimum cache lifetime"
- "Expiration of cached pages"

Boost had a patch http://drupal.org/node/326683, wonder if this somehow could be applied for the core cache.

Comment: Which version of Drupal you are looking at ?

Answer (score 5):

Just set the variable 'page_cache_maximum_age' using variable_set in custom module to the value 31536000

```
variable_set('page_cache_maximum_age', 31536000);
```

If you install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) Module there is a page for viewing and editing variables.

Above is a quick fix. If you want to do a perfect way then you need to form alter the "system_performance" form and change the option of below field.

```
  $period = drupal_map_assoc(array(0, 60, 180, 300, 600, 900, 1800, 2700, 3600, 10800, 21600, 32400, 43200, 86400), 'format_interval');
  $period[0] = '<' . t('none') . '>';
  $form['caching']['cache_lifetime'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Minimum cache lifetime'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('cache_lifetime', 0),
    '#options' => $period,
    '#description' => t('Cached pages will not be re-created until at least this much time has elapsed.')
  );
  $form['caching']['page_cache_maximum_age'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Expiration of cached pages'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('page_cache_maximum_age', 0),
    '#options' => $period,
    '#description' => t('The maximum time an external cache can use an old version of a page.')
  );
```

Comment: Have you thought of releasing a mini module? If not and you're ok with it, I might release this code as a module called Increase Page Cache Maximum Age

Comment: I am not sure community accepts as a mini module, since it's a small functionality. Yes, Give it a try :-) All the best !

Comment: Be sure that variable_set ran once. If you run variable_set on every page load it will flush the cache. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a custom module, you can also set these values in your site's settings.php file:

```
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 31536000;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 31536000;
```

These values won't show up in the /admin/development/performance screen, so if you need to check the values in force, you can use drush:

```
> drush vget cache_lifetime
> drush vget page_cache_maximum_age
```

Or, go with @Anil-sagar's suggestion and implement an override to the system performance form.